# Set widget initial size

Tags: c++, layout, gtk3

How can I set widget *initial* size in GTK+3?

I tried `gtk_widget_set_size_request(widget,w,h)` before the widget has been realized, and then `gtk_widget_set_size_request(widget,-1,-1)` to release the constraint (after the widget has been realize). This results in a larger window that has larger size, but the widget was size was minimized (it did not remember my initial size).

MCVE:

```
//@{"targets":[{"name":"initsize","type":"application","pkgconfig_libs":["gtk+-3.0"]}]}

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main()
    {
    gtk_init(NULL,NULL);
    auto window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    auto paned=gtk_paned_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),paned);

    auto scrollbox=gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL,NULL);
    gtk_paned_add1(GTK_PANED(paned),scrollbox);

    auto other=gtk_label_new("Right panel");
    gtk_paned_add2(GTK_PANED(paned),other);

    auto tv=gtk_text_view_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrollbox),tv);

    //Make the widget large
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(scrollbox,500,300); 
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    //Remove constraint. The new (larger) size of `window` is preserved as
    //desired, but `scrollbox` shrinks as a consequence of the constraint 
    //removal
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(scrollbox,-1,-1); 

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
    }
```

**Hint:** While creating this example, the problem appeared when I added the paned widget.

Here is a screenshot of how the desired *initial* layout. [image: Initial layout]

I achieved this by request sizes for the ScrolledWindow to the right, and for the GLArea to the right (without this, everything collapses to almost zero). After the UI is configured, it should be possible to shrink any of these panels, so the constraint must be removed *without affecting any sizes*. I also tried to preserve the paned position (get its value, remove constraint, and restore the old position, but that did not work).

Comment: Share a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: @theGtknerd Happy now?

Comment: `gtk_widget_set_size_request` *obtains* a size. To *set* a size you need `gtk_widget_size_allocate`

Comment: @Ripi2 Are you trying to say that there is a bug in GtkPaned?

Comment: No. Usually you retrieve sizes for contained windows, then distribute them and then set each window size.

Comment: @Ripi2 If you know the solution, write an answer.

Comment: I must be missing something obvious here. Why are you doing the size request on the scrollbox, when you want to downsize the window? Or ???

Comment: @theGtknerd I want to set a reasonable default size on the scrollbox, without forcing it to be that large. By default, the scrollbox becomes very small.

Without removing the constraint, the scrollbox will not shrink when the paned handle moves, hiding parts of the text view. But I only want to remove the constraint, not change the size. Or rather, set an initial size without setting any constraint (impossible?).

Comment: @user877329 OK, I see your edit. Let me think. Do you want to maximize on startup? This will make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest solution is probably to reverse the problem and set the size of the main window to the sum of the desired sizes, by using `gtk_window_set_default_size()`. Then use `gtk_paned_set_position ()` with the value for the leftmost widget. While this is only an approximate solution, it should be sufficient for most applications.

Comment: only calling `gtk_paned_set_position` will not increase the window size.

Comment: @user877329 Edited. By the way, this is going around in circles. First you want to set the container size, now you say you want to set the window size.

Comment: I want GTK to compute the window size, given an *initial* constraint on some of its children. Then I want to remove the constraint, so the user can resize widgets freely.

Comment: This is backwards from the normal way to use Gtk. Either set the initial window size, or set the size of the widget you want. No offense, but do you happen to be new to Gtk? Or could you explain (in full detail) what isn't working?

Comment: Maybe I tried to emulate a missing function: `gtk_widget_set_default_size`. If doing so is impossible, I will accept the solution of setting a default window size, despite I cannot possible know what size it should be. I want panel A to be 500 px wide and panel B 640 px wide. The window width will then be the sum of A and B, but must also include all margins, which is more-or-less impossible to compute reliably.

Comment: @user877329 Let me repeat myself. Do you want the window maximized? This would simplify things.

Comment: That would eat up too much valuable screenspace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152553/discussion-between-thegtknerd-and-user877329).